# Delete whole line in nano editor

Tags: command-line, nano

some times while I am editing my files with nano I am facing difficulty while deleting some big line, I need to hold Del key for long time.

is there any shortcut I can found to delete the total line at a time ?

I have checked the [man-page](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.1.html) , still no use.

Thank you.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to delete a line.

But strictly speaking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> does not delete lines permanently. The most recent set of deletions are stored in a buffer. These lines may be re-inserted at the current cursor location using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. You can use this to cut and paste.

Here you can find some [useful shortcuts](http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/sedwards/Nano/UsefulNanoKeyCommands.html) of [`nano`](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aeug)

Answer (score 6):

It's true that `man nano` is quite brief. However, if you have a "default" nano, you should see a small help menu at the bottom of the screen like this:

[image: nano help]

If you don't see such a menu, it is possible that you need to go into `/etc/nanorc` and look for something like this:

```
## Don't display the helpful shortcut lists at the bottom of the screen.
# set nohelp
```

Uncommenting the second line causes the menu to be hidden. You may prefer to copy `/etc/nanorc` to your home folder as `.nanorc` and edit *that* copy for user-specific modifications.

You can also access nano's built-in help (and shortcuts) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> at any time.

Comment: It's true that nano shows some of the shortcuts, but it's unclear what 'Cut Text' means.

Comment: cut, along with copy\paste are very universal functions